# Select and View Action with Id using form_tag and select_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to build a form that allows me to select a facility from a dropdown and then go to a show view when I click the submit_tag button. The form I created is below, it does a search, but not a direct view of the action with the id/parameter that I selected.

**facility model**

```
friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged]
```

friedlny
**routes**

```
 get 'chart_path/:id', "facilities#chart", as: :chart_path
```

**_form**

```
<%= form_tag chart_path, controller: 'facilities', method: :get, class: 'ui form' do %>
<%= select_tag :name, options_from_collection_for_select(Facility.where(is_chart_view_enabled: true), "name", "name"), {include_blank: 'Select Facility'} %>
<%= submit_tag 'Search', class: 'ui basic blue button' %>
<% end %>
```

**facilities_controller**

```
def chart
 @facility = Facility.friendly.find(params[:id)
end
```

Comment: so you want to `redirect_to chart_path @facility` in your controller action, don't know what views you have in place to handle that though.

Comment: alternatively you could just set up a view in the facilities view folder and just render that

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which rails version you are using. but if you are using 5+
you can try to build from using `form_with` or `form_for` for older verison

[form_with documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_with)

[form_for documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

```
<%= form_with chart_path, method: :get, class:'ui form' do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :name, options_from_collection_for_select(Facility.where(is_chart_view_enabled: true), "name", "name"), {include_blank: 'Select Facility'} %>
  <%= f.submit 'Search', class: 'ui basic blue button' %>
<% end %>
```

Tip: one more thing, the best practice is not doing database query in the view. you could create helper to put query in there.

Comment: I'm simply trying to traverse through 31 calendar day records with a previous and next button. If I click next, it will take me to July if i'm on June. If I click previous, it will take me to May. It'll show 31 records by month in each interval.